# Stopping video to play in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am loading a page in `UIWebView`. The page contain thumbnails to play. When I click any of the thumbnails, it launches in any default player. I want it should not play in default player, I want to play the video in `MPMovieController` With Custom controls whenever I click on the thumbnail in `UIWebview`. Could I stop the videos to play in default player??

Answer (score 0):

This would require to get the movie url and play it in MPMoviePlayer and stop the redirection of webview.

**LOGIC:**

in webview's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

get the URL from NSURLRequest's NSURL and then get the redirection url with `NSURL absoluteString`

compare the extension of the file in url. 
if it is of video e.g. .mov/.mp4,
load your MPMoviePlayer with the URL to play it in your application and `return NO;` for this delegate method.

Comment: This method is not calling when clicking on thumbnail of video.

Comment: have u set the webview's delegate to viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes,It is calling on load time

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to thumbnail code you can put `javascript` method which will do simple redirect:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:play_native_video_url(url); >thumbnail here</a>

play_native_video_url(url) {
     window.location = "play://"+url; 
}
```

`UIWebView` delegate will catch this redirect with custom scheme (not http:):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

// Define if it is your custom scheme:
  if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"play"]) {
      // get url and play it with native MPMoviePlayer...
      return NO;  // do not let WebView process it
  }
}
```

written from memory